# Can this laptop support an SSD hard drive upgrade?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, sata

I have in my hands an old [Samsung NP300E7A-S01IT laptop](https://www.samsung.com/uk/support/model/NP300E7A-S01IT/) that needs a hard drive upgrade since it became desperately slow with age.

What I want to do is upgrade its 10 years old [SATA HDD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpccW.jpg) into a SATA SSD.

As per my [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/1761508/old-laptop-wont-recognize-installed-ssd), what I already tried was buy a Samsung SSD 870 Evo, clone it and plug it in; which did not work.

On the [Crucial advisor tool](https://it.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/samsung/300e4a-300e5a-300e7a-3430ea-3530ea) it is shown that the product line supports SSDs, while on the [Samsung SSD finder tool](https://www.samsung.com/us/business/products/computing/ssd/finder/#/result/1138601) it is shown that the 860 Evo might be compatible, but I would like some confirmation before buying more hardware.

Is there a way to install *any* SSD onto this laptop at all?

Comment: 2.5" SATA III SSDs should be compatible with a device that supports 2.5" HDDs. There is no reason to believe it wouldn't work.

Comment: what version of Windows. I performed exactly the same upgrades years ago on half a dozen Windows 7/8/10 desktops and laptops with one issue, when I tried to mess around with partitions. If all I did was clone, it worked just fine

Comment: Voting to close this question since it is basically a dupe of the older question the same poster asked. [Old laptop won't recognize installed SSD](https://superuser.com/questions/1761508/old-laptop-wont-recognize-installed-ssd). And past any of this, a clean Windows install should work. Cloning the drive doesn’t work on Windows as it does on Linux systems.

Comment: @JaromandaX It's running Windows 10 and before that it was a Win 7 laptop.

Comment: What exactly happened after you cloned the 870 and plugged it in?  The exact error?  You might need to poke around in the BIOS depending on the error.

Comment: @cybernard Nothing happened. I plugged the SSD into the SATA port and the BIOS would't even see it.
Imagine the BIOS bootable device list with only the CD drive and all the other device empty, as if there was nothing plugged.
Furthermore the main page listed the SATA port ad empty/not connected.

Comment: Does your BIOS have a secure boot option and/or CSM?  Step 1 I would invert secure boot, and if that failed I would invert CSM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to re-install Windows when doing this, you are changing the hardware. The previous version of Windows was set up and installed on an HDD and was configured with those drivers.

Cloning the HDD to the SSD and then booting up, Windows does not know about the hardware changes/drivers needed.

Doing a clean install of Windows should fix your issue. You'll just have to copy over the data from the old driver by either uploading to the cloud, backup to an external storage device, or getting the needed equipment to attach the old HDD normally by HDD to USB adapter.

Comment: I've NEVER had an issue replacing a SATA hdd with a SATA ssd in windows 7 or later since a SATA drive is a SATA drive regardless of the physical nature of the data storage.

Comment: I had a Dell Latitude D-830 from 2007 with an 80 GB spinning HDD and I replaced it with a 120 GB Sandisk SATA SSD and restored a Macrium Reflect image to that. Worked totally fine straight away.